# How to split string by odd length

Tags: python-3.x, split

Lets say with a string = "AABBAAAAABBBBAAABBBBAA"
I want to return string split by the odd lengths of the string (i.e when A = 5 or A = 3),

What I want returned is 1) AABBAAAAA 2)BBBBAAA 3)BBBBAA,

How can I do that?

I tried using regex [A]+[B]+ for a slightly different case

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to regex iterate using `re.finditer` with the following pattern:

```
.*?(?:AAA(?:AA)?|$)
```

This pattern will non greedily consume until reaching either 3 A's, 5 A's, or the end of the string.  Then, we can print out each complete match as we iterate.

```
input = 'AABBAAAAABBBBAAABBBBAA'
pattern = '.*?(?:AAA(?:AA)?|$)'
for match in re.finditer(pattern, input):
    print match.group()
```

This prints:

```
AABBAAAAA
BBBBAAA
BBBBAA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
s = 'BBAAAAABBBBAAABBBBAA'

from itertools import groupby

out = ['']
for v, g in groupby(s):
    l = [*g]
    out[-1] += ''.join(l)
    if v == 'A' and len(l) in (3, 5):
        out.append('')

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['BBAAAAA', 'BBBBAAA', 'BBBBAA']
```